# OpenCart | Запретить вывод модуля на определенных страницах

Tags: php, html, mysql, opencart

Здравствуйте!
Нужно запретить вывод умного фильтра на некоторых категориях сайта, как это можно реализовать?

Например тут он ни к чему: http://op.truskahouses.in.ua/ingibitory

А здесь так как есть товары которые можно купить он нужен: http://op.truskahouses.in.ua/ingibitory/dzhenerik-tenofovir

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `..умного фильтра..` - это модуль, то он выводится в схеме "Категория", а она одна для всех категорий товаров. Самое простое для вас в этой ситуации это создать отдельную тему для отдельной категории:

- Создайте новую схему `Дизайн - Схемы - Добавить`. 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  В вашем случае в разделе `Модуль`, при создании схемы, просто не надо указывать тот экземпляр модуля, который выводит фильтры. Это вы можете посмотреть там же, `Дизайн - Схемы - Категория`. Остальные модули должны(желательно) полностью повторяться на тех же позициях.
- Перейдите в `Каталог Категории - Ваша Категория`. В её настойках перейдите на таб `Дизайн`, в выпадающем списке `Выберите макет:` выберите вашу новую схему.

Answer (score 0):

Не претендую на правильный ответ, давно занимался OpenCart: но это вроде делается созданием / редактированием схем. А вообще, у Вас выходит, что надо не отображать на странице категорий вот этот контейнер `<div class="catalogue__sidebar">...</div>`. Скорей всего посмотрите шаблон страницы категорий category.tpl, что там подставляется слева после вывода категорий. У меня в осStore 2.3 (OpenCart) это примерно `<div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>` - я туда рекламу от Гугл поместил. Но я действовал не придерживаясь концепции движка - правил вручную дефолтный шаблон. В сети много примеров.